# $$animateJs is not a function when using oclazyload, uigrid, and nganimate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-grid, ng-animate, oclazyload

I'm using Typescript 1.7, AngularJS 1.5.7, oclazyload 1.0.9, ui-grid 3.2.5, ui-router 0.3.1, requirejs 2.2.0

First, everything was working fine until I upgraded from Angular 1.4.3 to 1.5.7

In my code I pull in source like so from the require config:

```
shim: {
    'angular': {
        exports: 'angular',
        deps: ['Scripts/RequireJS/V.2.2.0/domReady!']
    },
    'ngSanitize': {
        deps: ['angular']
    },
    'ngAnimate': {
        deps: ['angular']
    },
    'ngTouch': {
        deps: ['angular']
    },
    'uiRouter': {
        deps: ['angular', 'ocLazyLoad']
    },
    'uiBootstrapTpls': {
        deps: ['angular']
    },
    'ocLazyLoad': {
        deps: ['angular', 'ngAnimate']
    },
```

Once the require calls complete I config angular and then call bootstrap manually.

the user comes to a login page, logs in, then goes to the homepage.  The homepage has a ui-grid, so we lazy load ( oc lazy loader ) on the state change like so:

```js
 $ocLazyLoad.load('uiGrid');
```

note uiGrid was configured in the angular module config call like this:

```js
$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
                events: true,
                jsLoader: requirejs,
                serie: true,
                modules: [

                    {
                        name: 'uiGrid',
                        files: ['Scripts/AngularUIGrid/V.3.2.5/ui-grid.min']

                    }
```

Now this all works just fine using Angular 1.5.7, but if I reload the page I get this:

```
TypeError: $$animateJs is not a function\n    
at prepareAnimation (http://myServer/Scripts/Angular/V.1.5.7/angular-animate.js?bust=2016_6_12_12_24:2152:14)\n    
at initDriverFn (http://myServer/Scripts/Angular/V.1.5.7/angular-animate.js?bust=2016_6_12_12_24:2136:16)\n    
at invokeFirstDriver (http://myServer/Scripts/Angular/V.1.5.7/angular-animate.js?bust=2016_6_12_12_24:3234:24)\n    
at Array.triggerAnimationStart (http://myServer/Scripts/Angular/V.1.5.7/angular-animate.js?bust=2016_6_12_12_24:3080:33)\n    
at nextTick (http://myServer/Scripts/Angular/V.1.5.7/angular-animate.js?bust=2016_6_12_12_24:423:15)\n    
at scheduler (http://myServer/Scripts/Angular/V.1.5.7/angular-animate.js?bust=2016_6_12_12_24:393:5)\n    
at Array.<anonymous> (http://myServer/Scripts/Angular/V.1.5.7/angular-animate.js?bust=2016_6_12_12_24:3102:9)\n    
at Scope.$digest (http://myServer/Scripts/Angular/V.1.5.7/angular.js?bust=2016_6_12_12_24:17338:55)\n    
at Scope.$apply (http://myServer/Scripts/Angular/V.1.5.7/angular.js?bust=2016_6_12_12_24:17553:24)\n    
at done (http://myServer/Scripts/Angular/V.1.5.7/angular.js?bust=2016_6_12_12_24:11698:47)
```

This didn't happen with 1.4.3 Angular.

A cursory lookindicated to me that when this happens it is because in angular-animate.js the DI of $$animateJs is undefined...therefore the displayed error message

```
var $$AnimateJsDriverProvider = ['$$animationProvider',     function($$animationProvider) {
  $$animationProvider.drivers.push('$$animateJsDriver');
  this.$get = ['$$animateJs', '$$AnimateRunner', function ($$animateJs,     $$AnimateRunner) {
```

Is oclazyload the problem, I looked at it a little bit and didn't know if maybe the way it decorates bootstrap and module could contribute?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi Brandon. Were you able to resolve this issue? I am also having the same problem, except, I'm not lazy-loading angular-animate.

Comment: Sorry, changed jobs last year and haven't been on here recently.  I don't think I resolved it, but I haven't been doing Angular since last June...

Answer (score -1):

The ui.grid has dependencies on ngAnimate so you need to load it in before loading ui.grid.

```
resolve: helper.resolveFor('ngAnimate','ui.grid')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I already load ngAnimate in the requirejs config, uiGrid lazy loads later once the person authenticates.  Everything is fine in that scenario, but once I'm logged in and if I reload the page the error shows, even though ngAnimate is again loaded first by requirejs before uiGrid is loaded.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35710288/5083812) The explanation is pretty clean.

Comment: That link doesn't seem to help really.  The OP even made a comment that it didn't work as posted it appears, but that they would just add uigrid without lazy loading and mark the answer correct.  In my case I made ocLazyLoad depend on ngAnimate, so I still don't see why this is happening and I really don't want to dig into the guts of angular and ui-grid at the moment.